Loop Cut Problem(too long)
I have another problem. Recently, I pressed "CTRL + N" to fix a problem with the Subdivision Surface Modifier. But now my loop cuts aren't accurate anymore. Can I solve it in any way or can I change it manualy (So i do not want the upward part)? Thanks for the help!

